# Flot chart combined tooltip of multiple series

Tags: flot, flot.tooltip

I have a flot chart with multiple series. I need to show y-values of all the series together when any point is hovered on for a particular x-value.

I'm using `flot.tooltip` for showing the tooltip. Is there any way to combine the y-values of all series like PowerBI does? Or or maybe even trigger the hovers of other points too?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I included in my chartOptions:

```
tooltipOpts: {
    content: function (label, x, y) {
        // titile
        var text = "<i>" + vm.areaData[0].data[x][0] + '<br/></i>';
        vm.areaData.forEach(function(series)
        {
            // series_label : value
            text += "<b>" + series.label + ' : ' + series.data[x][1] + "<br/>" + "</b>";
        });
        return text;
    }
}
```

As the X-axis has common values, I'm using that as title for the tooltip.
`vm.areaData` has the different series that are on my chart. I'm iterating through them and creating the tooltip that needs to be displayed.